# Showing Links Going To A Domain Or Page Using Nutch

Tags: nutch, web-crawler

I am using nutch and solr on ubuntu. I would like to use php to query the database or other methods to return an array of links from indexed pages that go to any particular url or domain. Please point me in the right direction.

I used this tutorial to set up the spider http://nlp.solutions.asia/?p=180

I would also like to note that the preference is for a php language option or an api interface with the nutch or sorl application via php curl or command line interface.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that inside of the database inlinks were stored so executing the following query would get indexed inbound links to creativecommons.org domain after parsing the inlinks from each row:

SELECT *
FROM webpage
WHERE inlinks LIKE '%creativecommons.org%'